# How to move the Koin ViewModel injection to the Base fragment?

Tags: android, viewmodel, koin

I am using Koin for dependency injection and also use injections for the ViewModel. I have *several Fragments* with the *corresponding ViewModel*.

```
class Fragment1 : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment1) { 
   private val viewModel: Fragment1ViewModel by inject()  
      
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.testVM1()
    }
}  
  
class Fragment2 : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment2) { 
   private val viewModel: Fragment2ViewModel by inject()  
      
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.testVM2()
    }
}
```

For all fragments I use **BaseFragment**

```
class BaseFragment(@LayoutRes private val layoutId: Int) : Fragment() {   

   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false)
}
```

**My goal** is to inject the ViewModel into the BaseFragment and use the variable in the child fragments.

I changed the code as follows:

```
class BaseFragment<T: ViewModel>(@LayoutRes private val layoutId: Int) : Fragment() {   
   val viewModel: TypeToken<T> by inject() 

   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false)
}   

class Fragment1 : BaseFragment<Fragment1ViewModel>(R.layout.fragment1) {

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.testVM1() // Unresolved reference: testVM1()
    }
}  

class Fragment2 : BaseFragment<Fragment2ViewModel>(R.layout.fragment2) { 

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.testVM2() // Unresolved reference: testVM2()
    }
}
```

But in this case I am getting an error `Unresolved reference: testVM1()/testVM2()` for calling methods in the child fragments.

**Question:** How do I change the code to make it work? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out my implementation.
This is a base fragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VM: ViewModel, VB: ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

protected abstract val viewModel: VM
protected lateinit var viewBinding: VB
private var _view: View? = null //cached view

protected abstract fun inflateViewBinding(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): VB
protected abstract fun bindViewBinding(view: View): VB

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    if(_view == null) {
        viewBinding = inflateViewBinding(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        _view = viewBinding.root
    } else {
        viewBinding = bindViewBinding(_view!!)
    }
    return _view
}
```

}

And, implement it to any other fragment like this:

```
class SplashFragment : BaseFragment<AuthViewModel, FragmentSplashBinding>() {

override val viewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModel()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {


    viewModel.someMethod()

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
} ....
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but can i move `by viewModel()` to `BaseFragment` and use `by viewModel()` with Generics? Because I want to use `viewModel` variable only from `BaseFragment`